# How do I create a reference in a function that doesn't change the value of the function's parameter?

Tags: java

I am new to java.
The question might not be that clear. Let me explain using code.
The code below is a function that prints out values in a linkedlist.
The first line of the function creates a reference to point to the same object that is pointed by the HeadNode reference. So any changes to currentNode will affect the object that HeadNode is pointing to. 
Now, inside the while loop, I am making the change of the currentNode, but I observe the linkedList didn't change after I exit the function. Why?

```
static void PrintLinkedList(ListNode HeadNode)
    {
        ListNode currentNode = HeadNode;
        while(currentNode != null)
        {
            System.out.println(currentNode.getData());
            currentNode = currentNode.getNext();
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

the reason of me bring this quesiton up is that when I implemented a function to reverse a linkedlist, my tempNode become null after the following code executed:

```
static ListNode ReverseLinkedList(ListNode headNode)
    {
        ListNode headNodeTemp = headNode;
        headNodeTemp.setNext(null);
        ListNode tempNode = headNode.getNext(); //temp becomes null because headNode is changed. Why??
        ListNode currentNode = headNodeTemp;
        while(tempNode != null)
        {...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So any changes to currentNode will affect the object that HeadNode is pointing to.

No, `currentNode` is a reference to the object `HeadNode` also refers to. You never change that object, all you change is what `currentNode` refers to.

```
currentNode = currentNode.getNext();
```

makes `currentNode` point to the next object, it doesn't change any object.

To change the object, you need to call a method or set a property,

```
currentNode.mutate();
currentNode.property = 17;
```

would change the pointed-to object, and these changes would be visible when the object is queried through `HeadNode`.

```
currentNode = currentNode.getNext();
```

just makes `currentNode` point to another object.

In

```
static ListNode ReverseLinkedList(ListNode headNode)
{
    ListNode headNodeTemp = headNode;
    headNodeTemp.setNext(null);
```

here, we call a method that changes the pointed-to object. Going by the name, it sets the `next` field to `null`. And the object `headNodeTemp` points to is the object `headNode` points to.

```
    ListNode tempNode = headNode.getNext(); //temp becomes null because headNode is changed. Why??
    ListNode currentNode = headNodeTemp;
    while(tempNode != null)
    {...
```

You should move the

```
ListNode tempNode = headNode.getNext();
```

line above the `setNext(null)` line.

```
static ListNode ReverseLinkedList(ListNode headNode)
{
    ListNode headNodeTemp = headNode;
    ListNode tempNode = headNode.getNext();
    headNodeTemp.setNext(null);
    ListNode currentNode = headNodeTemp;
    while(tempNode != null)
    {...
```

Comment: But currentNode refers to that object. So any changes in currentNode changes the object. Right?

Comment: No, `currentNode` is just a variable holding the address of the object. Changes to `currentNode` change what `currentNode` points to. To change the object that `currentNode` points to, you must invoke a method or set a property. `currentNode.mutate();` would mutate the object.

Comment: Please read mine, I hope that clarifies it. If not, ping me. If you don't want to change the object, you mustn't call any methods on it that change it. But I think it's probably a matter of order.

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing objects and references.

`currentNode = x` does not change the object that `currentNode` points to.  Rather, it changes the `currentNode` *variable* to point to a different object.

That does not affect any other fields or variables that happen to point to the old object.

Answer (score 0):

In agreement with the other posts. All arguments are pass-by-value in Java - Demonstration:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List a = new ArrayList();
    a.add("Fred");

    changeA(a);
    // contents of a is "Fred" not "Barney" (change to 'a' not reflected back here)
    // because all arguments are Pass-By-Value

    addToA(a);
    // contents of a is "Fred" AND "Barney"

    int b = 10;    

    changeB(b);
    // b = 10 (not 20)
}

static void changeA(List a) {
    a = new ArrayList(); // a is now a different object
    a.add("Barney");
}

static void addToA(List a) {
    a.add("Barney");
}

static void changeB(int b) {
    b = 20;
}
```